# Matlab image centroid simulation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, gaussian

I was given this task, I am a noob and need some pointers to get started with centroid calculation in Matlab:

Instead of an image first I was asked to simulate a Gaussian distribution(2 dimensional), add noise(random noise) and plot the intensities, now the position of the centroid changes due to noise and I need to bring it back to its original position by 
-clipping level to get rid of the noise, noise reduction by clipping or smoothing, sliding average (lpf) (averaging filter 3-5 samples ), calculating the means or using Convolution filter kernel - which does matrix operations which represent the 2-D images

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted so far and where you are getting stuck?

Comment: I tried using pdf function to simulate a gaussian distribution and randn to generate the noise and added them together, like this:         x = -5:0.01:5
p1 = normpdf(x,0,1);
plot(x,p1)
n1 = randn(size(p1))
but the problem is after adding the noise it doesn't look like gaussian distribution anymore

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a noob, even if we wrote down the answer verbatim you probably won't understand how it works. So instead I'll do what you asked, give you pointers and you'll have to read the related documentation :

a) to produce a 2-d Gaussian use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) or [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)

b) to add noise to the image look into `rand` ,`randn` or `randi`, depending what exactly you need.

c) to plot the intensities use `imagesc`

d) to find the centroid there are several ways, try to further search SO, you'll find many discussions. Also you can check TMW File exchange for different implementations for that.